# One repository with many nested repositories that are not virtual (submodules or subtree)

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to create one big repository which then contains multiple child repositories that are physically and not virtually maintained by the parent? I tried submodules and I found that it is actually a pointer to another repository. I found subtree to be something similar as well.

What I need is that, I do not want create a separate git repository for each small module belonging to the same project but I want those small module to be repositories themselves. The reason behind this is that, I use Go and I want to run the `go get` command on subdirectories in the main repository. Does git support this?

Comment: I'm not sure how this could even theoretically work. If you commit a change to one of these sub-projects, where is that commit stored - in the sub-project's history, or the full project's, or somehow in both? It seems like you might be better off approaching from the other side: what options does `go get` have for fetching something other than a full repository.

Comment: @IMSoP: Yes you are right, there are some theoretical issues involved in this approach. Let me rephrase it in better words, can we create a Project (which is not a repository) but has repositories attached to it. So that I can organize things and group them together?

Comment: That probably depends on what tools you use _outside of_ git. I see you've tagged the question with [tag:github], although you don't mention that anywhere in the text; I'm not aware of any tools there for grouping multiple repositories, though.

Comment: @IMSoP: My github has become a mess of small projects that belong to the same context. So I'd like to group things as Microservices, Infrastructure Layer, Front-Ends, etc.